# twitter typeahead wrong input value

Tags: javascript

after selecting a suggestion and submitting a form I see that is a wrong value of the input field. I received the value of "desc" from the php file. I want to have the value of "DS" from the php file, what is wrong (i think in the js-code)?

```
$('#orga_name').typeahead(null, 
    {
      name: 'orga_name_autosuggest',
      displayKey: 'desc',
      input: 'value',
      highlight: true,
      hint: false,
      limit: 5,
      minLength: 2,
      wildcard: '%QUERY',
      source: datas.ttAdapter(),
      templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
          '<div class=\"media\">',
                '<div class=\"pull-left\">',
                    '<div class=\"media-object\">',
                        '<img src=\"{{img}}\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\"/>',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class=\"media-body\">',
                    '<h4 class=\"media-heading\">{{value}}</h4>',
                    '<p>{{desc}}</p>',
                '</div>',
          '</div>',
        ].join(''))
      }
    });
```

The given php array

```
$results[] = array(
      "value" => $res['DS'],
      "desc" => $res['ORG_NAME'],
      "img" => "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/?" . (rand(1, 10000) . rand(1, 10000)),
      "tokens" => array($query, $query . rand(1, 10))
    );
```

Comment: No `<form>` element appears at Question? Have you tried changing `displayKey` to `"value"`?

Comment: if i change to display:value, i have two unwanted thinks. first: the live-typeahead wont work in the field, second thing is that i see the value in the input field. what i want is to see the value of the "desc" and submit the value of "DS"

Comment: What is `<form>` at `html`? Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate?